# TabLayout is not displaying tabs properly in tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_dealer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_dealer_type_background"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/background"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/action_bar_background"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/action_bar_background">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HPCL"
                />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IOCL"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BPCL"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

This is my tablayout code in the xml file.

Here is the backgroudn.xml in drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/action_bar_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

And the final tab_dealer_type_background file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/action_bar_background" />
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now what is happening when I use these files for handset, it displays tabs properly. But when I use the same code in tablet, it includes white spaces on the left and right end of the tablayout.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem here? What I am missing here? I have tried a lot of things but i am not able to rectify it. If anybody knows how is this happening please tell me?

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshots?

Comment: Just added the badly formatted tablayout

Comment: remove this from tablayout:  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: @SatanPandeya : No change, it just shifted to the left side from the center

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_dealer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_dealer_type_background"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/background"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/action_bar_background"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/action_bar_background">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HPCL" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="IOCL" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BPCL" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

This is how I did it.